# Restore iphone 6 running iOS 9.0.1 from old iOS 8.x.x backup using iTunes? Same phone, different iCloud accounts

Tags: iphone, itunes, restore, activation-lock, two-step-authentication

I lent my mom my backup iPhone running iOS 9 after she lost her Android.  She created an iCloud account in order to turn on Find My iPhone so she wouldn't lose it. Never linked the account to an email and proceeded to forget the password and lock herself out of the account. She doesn't really remember what she wrote as her birth date but thinks (thinks!!!) she might have given the correct answers to the security questions. Which is irrelevant unless I can come up with whatever birth date she gave the server.  Right now I have normal access to the phone including connecting to iTunes with my own account, just unable to do anything or disconnect from her account within iCloud. 
I have an old backup from the same phone in iTunes created with my own Apple ID when I upgraded from iOS 8 to iOS 9. If I used this backup to restore, will I finally be able to connect to iCloud using my own account? I have a feeling it won't work but I had to ask.
PS: She was sent a 6 digit code to input in a trusted device, but the only trusted device for that account is still the same phone.